# Pandas append series from tuple into empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a dataframe with a certain logic.

Here's my attempt:

```
def split_df(df: pd.DataFrame):
    train = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
    valid = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
    i = 0
    for data in tqdm(df.iterrows()):
        if i > 10:
            break
        if (len(valid[valid['category_id'] == data[1]['category_id']]) > 0):
            tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, data = pd.Series(data[1]))
            train.append(tmp,ignore_index=True)
            i = i+1
        else:
            tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, data = pd.Series(data[1]))
            train.append(tmp,ignore_index=True)
            valid.append(tmp,ignore_index=True)
            i = i+1
    return (train, valid)
```

When I run this, I get a tuple of empty dataframes. 
the i<10 is just for me to check outputs. 
The splitting logic may be wrong, but it's not important for now. 
I also try to avoid for loops, so if there's a better approach to this problem, I'll be glad to read about it.

Comment: Hey, if you need a better approach, it might be good to post a minimum reproducible example and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append does not modify the dataframe in place, so you need to reassign your variable to keep changes:

```
train = train.append(tmp,ignore_index=True)
valid = valid.append(tmp,ignore_index=True)
```